# Method outputs object references instead of column data when included as a module ( Rails 4.2 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I referred this [railcasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true) for generating csv file of my model. For generating csv file of products data

```
#products.rb


def self.to_csv(options = {})
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << column_names
    all.each do |product|
      csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

And works like a charm. But I need to have the same csv generating function across my app and so I wrote a module

```
lib/generate_csv.rb


module GenerateCSV
  def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |thismodel|
        csv << thismodel.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and I included this module in

```
#products.rb
include GenerateCSV
```

but this doesn't work. In the downloaded file there is no data except object references like `#<Product:0x007fdbe6a18578>`. Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved your example into [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-included) and it works. Here is the code:

```
# app/models/reason.rb
class Reason < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CsvExportable

  belongs_to :project

  scope :fresh, -> { where("created_at > ? ", DateTime.now) }
  scope :expired, -> { where("created_at < ? ", DateTime.now) }
end

# app/models/concerns/csv_exportable.rb
module CsvExportable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.to_csv(options = {})
      CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
        csv << column_names
        all.each do |thismodel|
          csv << thismodel.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

[4] pry(main)> r = Reason.all
  Reason Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "reasons".* FROM "reasons"
=> [#<Reason:0x007faf5c15e3d0 id: 1, name: "r1", project_id: nil, created_at: Thu, 30 Jun 2016 07:50:10 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Thu, 30 Jun 2016 07:50:10 UTC +00:00, deleted: false>,
 #<Reason:0x007faf5c15e240 id: 3, name: "r2", project_id: 1, created_at: Fri, 22 Jul 2016 04:53:11 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Fri, 22 Jul 2016 04:53:11 UTC +00:00, deleted: false>]
[5] pry(main)> r.to_csv
  Reason Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "reasons".* FROM "reasons"
=> "id,name,project_id,created_at,updated_at,deleted\n1,r1,,2016-06-30 07:50:10 UTC,2016-06-30 07:50:10 UTC,false\n3,r2,1,2016-07-22 04:53:11 UTC,2016-07-22 04:53:11 UTC,false\n"
[6] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Thank you, what do u think the reason its not working when included straight as a module?

Comment: @Maverick Tan said why it doesn't working, so he is right. Concern is just a "rails way". If you move self.to_csv from `included` block, you'll get the object references just like in your question.

Answer (score 0):

extend GenerateCSV instead of include it since `to_csv` is a class method

```
module GenerateCSV
  def to_csv(options = {})
  end
end 

#products.rb
extend GenerateCSV
```